# One to many masked communication twilio proxy service

Tags: php, proxy, twilio

I am using the twilio php library to send the first message to my customers using Twilio number when the customer replies to that number at this point proxy session will create and add both (customer and company) into that session.

company will receive the customer replies using a new generated proxy number
"till this is working fine" but if a company replies back to that message, the customer will get a response from new generated proxy number rather than old Twilio number.

The text below explains the process:

1. Send the first Message:

```
    Twilio number       Customer number
    (xxxxxx6840)  --->  (xxxxxx6866)
```

2. Customer Replies:

```
    Customer number        Twilio number       Proxy number         Company number
    (xxxxxx6866)     --->  (xxxxxx6840)  --->  (xxxxxx6872)  --->   (xxxxxx2786)
```

Up to this point, everything is working fine.

3. Company replies

```
    Company number       Proxy number     Customer number
    (xxxxxx2786)   --->  (xxxxxx6872)---> (xxxxxx6866)
```

If the company replies, then the customer gets that reply from new proxy number.
What we wants is:

```
Company number       Proxy number     Twilio number      Customer number
(xxxxxx2786)   --->  (xxxxxx6872)---> (xxxxxx6840)  ---> (xxxxxx6866)
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for this? Do you start the session with the regular Twilio Messaging API or by creating [Participants](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/participant) for a proxy session?

Comment: Hey Philnash thanks for the valueable time,this issue is resoved, i added the twilio number as reserved in number pool and just set the outOfsessionCallbackUrl that it.

Comment: Good to hear you solved this!

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps documented here, for out of session call backs?

Out-of-Session Callback Response Guide
https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/out-session-callback-response-guide

Following that process should provide the scenario you are looking for.

Also, this adds more insight.

Using the Reserved Numbers and Auto-Create functionalities to support the “online directory” scenarios
https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/using-the-reserved-numbers-and-auto-create-functionalities-to-support-the-online-directory-scenarios

Comment: Hey Alan, thanks for your reply but my question is different, i don't want to display new proxy number to my customer they will only get a response from old twilio number.